# Problem when send pdf file from Android to nodeJS server

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-studio, file

I have a button in html file when it is pressed it calls al function chooseFile() in MainActivity.java and auto send the data to the server.
Script in html:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("chooseFile").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        Android.chooseFile();
    });
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface;
    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/upload.html");
    }
public class WebAppInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void chooseFile() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File"), 1);
        }
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String filePath = uri.getPath();
                sendPDF(this,uri);
            }
        }
    }

public static void sendPDF(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
        new AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
                Uri uri = uris[0];
                try {           
                    URL url = new URL("http://Ipv4/upload");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

                    conn.setReadTimeout(35000);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(35000);

                    // Open InputStream from Uri
                    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                    // Write data from InputStream to output stream
                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                    inputStream.close();

                    // Process response...

                    conn.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
        }.execute(fileUri);
    }
```

This is my server:

```
const uploadDirectory = 'uploads';

// Create the uploads directory if it doesn't exist
if (!fs.existsSync(uploadDirectory)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(uploadDirectory);
}

// Set up Multer storage configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// POST route for file upload
app.post('/upload', upload.single('myFile'), async (req, res) => {
    // File upload successful
    console.log('File uploaded:', req.file);
});

// Start the server
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3001');
});
```

The logcat after i choose file:

```
2023-06-17 16:21:27.807   979-2356  TrafficStats            com.example.verifycertificate        D  tagSocket(183) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2023-06-17 16:21:27.813   979-1008  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.verifycertificate        E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-06-17 16:21:29.423   979-1008  EGL_emulation           com.example.verifycertificate        D  app_time_stats: avg=166.52ms min=4.56ms max=1404.14ms count=9
```

When try to get full file path ( the file path when i use uri.getPath(); is: /document/document: 100002321 ) so i try to use URI to send file. But the server doesn't resposne anything.

My problem is i dont see the file is send to the server, i dont know the file is send or not. The server should show the message in console (console.log('File uploaded:', req.file);) but i dont see anything.

Comment: Uri.getPath() gives you a nonsense path as you saw and could have determined yourself if you had used File.exists() on ut before upload.

Comment: You have a nice content scheme uri visible with Uri toString(). Use the uri to handle the file.

Comment: I see now that you do not use that wrong 'path'. Instead you opened an InputStream for that uri. Well that is the way to go. You dont need that 'path'. What is your problem?

Comment: @blackapps My problem is i dont see the file is send to the server, i dont know the file is send or not. The server should show the message in console (console.log('File uploaded:', req.file);) but i dont see anything

Comment: `i dont know the file is send or not.` Well you can know it if you knew what your asynctask did. Tell how it runned? Did you look in the logcat for exceptions? And why not add some log statements. And why not implement an onPostExecute() to inform the user -and yourself- how doInBackground() executed?

Comment: `// Process response...` You are not determining the response. Do it if you wanna know what happens.